# How to remove underline from dynamically created hyperlink in xaml?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, hyperlink, windows-phone-8.1

I am building an app for Windows Phone 8.1/10 and I need to put `Hyperlink` inside `TextBlock` element.

I created an instance of `TextBlock` then added a few `Run`'s to `TextBlock.Inlines` and also a `Hyperlink`. I need that `Hyperlink` just for it's `Click` event.

Well I successfully achieved what I am trying to do. But I cannot remove `Underline` from `Hyperlink`

What I want to do is a `TextBlock` with clickable areas in it. Like:

`Hello **@clickablething**, how are you today?`

It seems like WP8.1/WM10 Runtime applications does not support `TextBlock.TextDecorations`

Well my question is is there any alternative to `Hyperlink` that contains  `Click or Tapped` event? Or how can I remove underline of hyperlink?

Comment: EDIT: "someone was asked why I do not use click event of textblock"... (Well, first of all TextBlock does not contain a Click event, instead it has Tapped event. The thing is that I do not want TextBlock to be a clickable element, instead I need specific Run element(s) to be clickable inside InlineCollection of TextBlock element.)

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own control template for your hypelink and remove the underline in this template. I found this link:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296242(v=vs.95).aspx

At the end of this template you can see:

```
<TextBlock
                      x:Name="UnderlineTextBlock"
                      Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                      HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                      VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                      Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                      TextDecorations="Underline"
                      Visibility="Collapsed"/>
```

Remove the TextDecoration="Underline" and you should be done.

The link is about the silverlight version of WPF but it should be similar in your case.

Comment: Yeah I know but: `The property 'TextDecorations' was not found in type 'TextBlock'.`